# AdaptiveChars v1.2 Schema Updates

Tags: json, adaptive-cards

I see AdaptiveCards v1.2.0 was released a few days ago. It is described as having implemented the "wrap" property for ChoiceSet; however, I don't see this property in the schema of the downloaded package. Can we get confirmation that this was in-fact implemented in 1.2 and working? I've not been able to test this out due to other commitments, but am working with a customer who is needing this property.
This is item #14 on the below 1.2 release:
https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/releases/tag/v1.2.0

In the 1.2.0 source, here is the schema for ChoiceSet from schemas/adaptive-card.json:

```
        "Input.ChoiceSet": {
            "additionalProperties": true,
            "type": "object",
            "description": "Allows a user to input a Choice.",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/CardElement"
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "choices": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "description": "`Choice` options.",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Input.Choice"
                    }
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Unique identifier for the value. Used to identify collected input when the Submit action is performed."
                },
                "isMultiSelect": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "description": "Allow multiple choices to be selected.",
                    "default": false
                },
                "style": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/ChoiceInputStyle"
                },
                "type": {
                    "description": "Must be `\"Input.ChoiceSet\"`.",
                    "enum": [
                        "Input.ChoiceSet"
                    ],
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The initial choice (or set of choices) that should be selected. For multi-select, specify a comma-separated string of values."
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "type",
                "id",
                "choices"
            ]
        },
```

I don't see the "wrap" property listed here.

Comment: I don't know of any channels that have adopted Adaptive Cards 1.2 support. What channel are you using?

Comment: Teams channel - I know they officially only support 1.0, but it does seem to work with 1.1, but doesn't seem to work at all with 1.2. All of that aside, the main point is, has the schema been updated? If not, could that cause issues when attempting to use the property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for asking about this. This is Andrew from the Adaptive Cards team.

The schema file you were looking at back at the beginning of June seems to be the old 1.1 schema. It's possible we didn't have the 1.2 schema published yet at that time.

Here's the new 1.2 schema, which indeed does have `wrap` on `Input.ChoiceSet`: https://adaptivecards.io/schemas/1.2.0/adaptive-card.json

Also, on our docs, you can see the `wrap` property: https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.ChoiceSet.html

Let us know if you have any further questions!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Teams does not currently support Adaptive Cards 1.2.

Comment: yes, you're right as I already mentioned, but that's not the point of the question

Comment: The only question I'm seeing is "Can we get confirmation that this was in-fact implemented in 1.2 and working?" It is by definition neither implemented nor working if it's not supported at all.

Comment: so you're confirming that even though the "wrap" functionality was added as a feature in 1.2, it's not yet implemented and thus does not work as described?

Comment: I think there may be some confusion here but I don't know exactly where it is so I'll take a guess. Adaptive Cards do not exist in a void. Adaptive Cards are just a JSON schema that an application can interpret however it pleases. If Adaptive Cards releases a new version, that just means there is a new schema that applications have the option of interpreting, if someone chooses to program the application to do so. The schema does not do anything by itself. So it makes no sense at all to ask if it works if there isn't an application that has been programmed to interpret that particular JSON.

Comment: I'll go about this a different way, first what purpose does the schemas/adaptive-card.json file serve?

Comment: Like all JSON schemas it serves the purpose of determining if JSON is valid. In this case it also helps provide documentation describing the way Adaptive Cards are expected to behave. Since it sounds like you're taking issue with the JSON schema not being updated to reflect v1.2, the place to post those concerns would be on the GitHub repo, but it looks like there's already a pending pull request: https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/pull/3041

Comment: I did see the PR, I assume it's this one: https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/pull/3041
if that's the case, then that tells me the schema has not been updated yet, but is in the process. That answers my original concern.

Comment: I'm glad your concern could be answered. Please remember to upvote this answer and mark it as correct.